# How to manage file versions with git if files are owned by root and non-root users?

Tags: linux, git, sudo, root

I have root owned files and other files in a directory and I would like to use git for version control of these files. Is it possible to use same git repo for files owned by root and non-root users or is it just asking for troubles?

I made a simple test where I created a repo as ordinary user, checked in and out some files and the checked in root owned files by using `sudo git add`, `sudo git commit` because ordinary user does not have read access to these files.
After this `.git/index` is owned by root and ordinary user cannot run e.g. git add, git commit.

What is the recommended way to manage versions if files are owned by root and non-root users?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `core.sharedRepository` to `group` to set permissions on a repository to be shared with a group.  Then, set the setgid bit on the root of the repository and each directory under it, and change the group for each file and directory to a group that each user is a part of (or at least the non-root users).

That will ensure that Git writes all of the files in the tree to share permissions with a given group, and that the group for all files and directories will be the same: that of the containing directory.